# Profile access on Custom Fields in Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, custom-permission

In Einstein Analytics, to see what field permission a User has on a Custom Field via Permission Sets can be achieved using combining FieldPermissions object and PermissionSetAssignment Object.

But, I am looking for an Object that would give me field permissions a User has on Custom Fields via Profiles. I looked into the Objects that are available in Einstein Analytics but couldn't find any suitable object.

Is it not possible to achieve via Analytics? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for some days, I was able to find the Object that would give me field permissions a User has on Custom Fields via Profiles. It's PermissionSet.

I learned the object field access of a Profile is stored in Permission Sets but as standard PermissionSet and these are not visible. There's a Boolean field 'IsOwnedByProfile' on permission set object that differentiates between the Custom Permission Sets and Standard ones(via Profiles).

Hope it helps someone.